# jquery data attributes in plugin find parent

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

having this simple jquery plugin which loads data via ajax if a given data attribute exists on element with classname "async" I try to identify where the data should be wrapped but without any result

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.asyncLoader = function(options) {
    var $self = this;
    var settings = $.extend({}, options);
    var attributes = [];
    return this.each(function(i) {
      attributes = $(this).data();
      $.each(attributes, function(key, value) {
        if (key == 'load') {
          if (value.target) {
            var el = $('.async').filter('[data-load = \'{"target" : "' + value.target + '" }\' ]');
            el.load(value.target)
          }
        }
      });
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

the markup would look like

```
<div class="async" data-load = '{"target": "/my-target"}'></div>
```

How do I find parent element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a callback to `filter()` instead,

```
var el = $('.async').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('load') === '{"target": "'+ value.target +'"}'
});
```

or below - *this might require additional checks for objects.

```
var el = $('.async').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('load').target == value.target
});
```

Comment: Great! Glad it helped. Please accept the answer if you're happy with it.